# Digit Counter Fibonacci List Haskell trouble

Tags: haskell

So, for problem 25 in Project Euler, I have to find the position of the first number in the Fibonacci sequence with a thousand digits.

```
-- Lazily generates an infinite Fibonacci series
fib :: [Int]
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)

-- Checks if given number has a thousand digits.
checkDigits :: Int -> Bool
checkDigits number = length (show number) == 1000

-- Checks if position in Fibonacci series has a thousand digits.
checkFibDigits :: Int -> Bool
checkFibDigits pos = checkDigits (fib !! (pos - 1))

p25 = head (filter (\x -> checkFibDigits x == True) ([1..]))
```

For some reason, this approach seems to hang indefinitely. If I replace 1000 with 10, it spits out 45, which is the position of the first number with 10 digits.

Either my approach is crazy inefficient, or Haskell's doing something weird with big numbers. A similar approach in Python worked pretty flawlessly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `filter (\x -> checkFibDigits x == True) ([1..]))` ***UGH!!!***. Do you realize that's *exactly* as doing: `filter checkFibDigits [1..]`?

Comment: Let me clarify what @Bakuriu wrote: `a == True` is `a` for any `a`. also, `\x -> f x` is `f`. Thus, `(\x -> checkFibDigits x == True)` can be reduced to `(\x -> checkFibDigits x)` and from that into `checkFibDigits`.

Comment: I get it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem is using `Int` rather than `Integer` in the type of `fib`, which limits the values to never go above around 2<sup>31</sup>, but beyond that, yes, the way you’re doing it is pretty inefficient. Namely, it’s O(n<sup>2</sup>) when it really ought to be O(n). The way you’re generating the Fibonacci sequence is fine, but when trying to find the first value that’s a thousand digits, you go:

- Is the first element of the Fibonacci sequence greater than 1000 digits? No, move on…
- Is the second element [which, oh wait, I need to get from this linked list, so I better follow the ‘next’ pointer some number of times] greater than 1000 digits? No, move on…
- …
- Is the 50th element [better start at the beginning of the linked list, follow the next pointer, follow the next pointer, follow the next pointer, …, and fetch the value at this element] greater than 1000 digits? No, move on…
- …

Basically, you’re re-traversing the linked list each and every single time. A different approach might be to zip together the index and corresponding Fibonacci result:

```
ghci> take 10 $ zip [1..] fib
[(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,5),(6,8),(7,13),(8,21),(9,34),(10,55)]
```

Then you drop elements until the Fibonacci value is at least 1000 digits, and take the index of the first one left:

```
ghci> fst $ head $ dropWhile ((< 1000) . length . show . snd) $ zip [1..] fib
4782
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change `Int` to `Integer` for `fib` and `checkDigits`, you will notice that the answer will appear instantaneously:

```
fib :: [Integer]
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)

checkDigits :: Integer -> Bool
checkDigits number = length (show number) == 1000
```

That's because `Int` has limited size whereas `Integer` has an arbitrary precision which is limited by your system memory.